# AWS Lambda Error with Puppeteer and chrome-aws-lambda: Cannot Find Module '/var/task/puppeteer/lib/Browser'

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, puppeteer, chromium, aws-lambda-layers

#### Problem:

I am deploying a Node.js function on AWS Lambda using AWS CDK, which utilizes Puppeteer with the chrome-aws-lambda package for PDF generation. Despite following the documentation and examples, I am receiving an error indicating that the module '/var/task/puppeteer/lib/Browser' cannot be found. This error occurs at runtime when the Lambda function is invoked. The error is as follows:

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module '/var/task/puppeteer/lib/Browser'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
  "trace": [
    "Error: Cannot find module '/var/task/puppeteer/lib/Browser'",
    ...
  ]
}
```

#### Environment Details:

- Node.js version: 20.x
- AWS CDK version: 2.115.0
- Puppeteer version: 21.7.0 (used via puppeteer-core)
- chrome-aws-lambda version: 10.1.0

#### Lambda Layer Setup:

The Lambda layer for Chromium is created with the following structure:

```
nodejs/
└── node_modules/
    ├── chrome-aws-lambda/
    └── puppeteer-core/
```

#### CDK Definitions:

```
this.chromiumLayer = new LayerVersion(this, "chromiumLayer", {
  code: Code.fromAsset(join(__dirname, "../../src/layers/chromium")), // Also tried .zip
  compatibleRuntimes: [Runtime.NODEJS_20_X],
  description: "Chromium layer for Lambda",
});
```

#### Lambda Function:

In my Lambda function, I'm importing and using chrome-aws-lambda as follows:

```
import chromium from 'chrome-aws-lambda';

async function createPdf(...) {
  const browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
    ...
  });
  // rest of the function code
}
```

#### The function is part of a CDK stack and defined as follows:

```
this.createDownloadPDF = new NodejsFunction(this, "createDownloadPDF", {
  runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
  ...
  layers: [this.chromiumLayer],
  ...
});
```

#### Attempts to Resolve:

- Ensured that `puppeteer-core` and `chrome-aws-lambda` are not bundled with the Lambda function's deployment package.
- Checked that the Lambda layer is attached correctly.
- Verified that the local setup works fine, but the issue occurs only in the AWS Lambda environment.

I'm looking for insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Has anyone faced a similar problem or can offer guidance on troubleshooting this further?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to download the binaries at runtime and not use any layers, or other mechanisms.

I explain it on this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77855668/5570762