# AWS CDK TypeScript Lambda Error: 'chromium.executablePath is not a function' with Puppeteer and Custom Chromium Layer

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, puppeteer, chromium

### Issue with AWS CDK, TypeScript Lambda, and Lambda Layers - `chromium.executablePath` Not a Function

I am working on an AWS Lambda function in TypeScript using AWS CDK for deployment. My Lambda function utilizes Puppeteer and a custom Chromium build to generate PDFs. However, I am encountering a `TypeError` related to `chromium.executablePath`.

#### Layer Dependencies:

My `package.json` includes the following dependencies for the Lambda Layer:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@sparticuz/chromium": "^106.0.2",
  "puppeteer-core": "^18.0.5"
}
```

#### Lambda Function:

Here is the relevant part of my Lambda function:

```js
const puppeteer = require("/opt/nodejs/puppeteer-core");
const chromium = require("/opt/nodejs/@sparticuz/chromium");

async function createPdf(fileLinks: Record<string, string>, logoDataUri: string, bucketName: string, key: string): Promise<Buffer> {
  await chromium.font("https://raw.githack.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji/master/fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf"); // Add Font

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: chromium.args,
    defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
    executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
    headless: chromium.headless,
  });

  // ... rest of the function
}

// Function logic continues...
```

#### Error Encountered:

When invoking the Lambda, I receive the following error:

```json
{
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "chromium.executablePath is not a function",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: chromium.executablePath is not a function",
    "    at createPdf (/var/task/index.js:70735:36)",
    "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)",
    "    at async Runtime.handler (/var/task/index.js:70601:21)"
  ]
}
```

#### CDK Definitions:

Here's how I defined the layer and the Lambda function in my CDK stack:

```js
this.chromiumLayer = new LayerVersion(this, "chromiumLayer", {
  code: Code.fromAsset(join(__dirname, "../../src/layers/chromium")),
  compatibleRuntimes: [Runtime.NODEJS_20_X],
  compatibleArchitectures: [Architecture.X86_64, Architecture.ARM_64],
  description: "Chromium layer for Lambda",
});

this.createDownloadPDF = new NodejsFunction(this, "createDownloadPDF", {
  // ... configuration properties
  layers: [this.chromiumLayer],
  bundling: {
    externalModules: ["aws-sdk", "@sparticuz/chromium", "puppeteer-core"],
    // ... other bundling options
  },
});
```

#### tsconfig:

```
"paths": {
  "/opt/nodejs/puppeteer-core": ["./src/layers/chromium/nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer-core"],
  "/opt/nodejs/@sparticuz/chromium": ["./src/layers/chromium/nodejs/node_modules/@sparticuz/chromium"]
}
```

#### Question:

1. Why am I getting the `TypeError: chromium.executablePath is not a function` error?
2. Is there a specific way to bundle or configure the Lambda layers in AWS CDK for this kind of setup?
3. Are there additional steps I need to take to correctly integrate `@sparticuz/chromium` with Puppeteer in a Lambda environment?

Any insights or solutions to address this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: any idea about this ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78104060/dirname-is-not-defined-in-es-module-scope-in-aws-lambda-puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many ways and the only one that worked with Nodejs.18+ was to download the chromium binaries at runtime.

This requires no layers, external dependencies, or anything else. The main disadvantage is the cold start: now your lambda needs to download and decompress a ~58MB binary from a remote location (I recommend uploading to S3).

I describe the solution here: https://open.substack.com/pub/konarskis/p/puppeteer-aws-lambda

Answer (score 0):

#### Discoveries

I found that using a `NodejsFunction` offered other problems that I mitigated through using a JS lambda function

#### Working Solution:

**CDK Code:**

```
this.chromiumLayer = new LayerVersion(this, "chromiumLayer", {
  code: Code.fromAsset(join(__dirname, "../../src/layers/chromium")),
  compatibleRuntimes: [Runtime.NODEJS_18_X],
  compatibleArchitectures: [Architecture.X86_64, Architecture.ARM_64],
  description: "Chromium layer for Lambda",
});

this.createDownloadPDF = new aws_lambda.Function(this, "createDownloadPDF", {
  runtime: aws_lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
  code: aws_lambda.Code.fromAsset(join(__dirname, "./createDownloadPDF")),
  handler: "index.handler",
  memorySize: 1024,
  logRetention: RetentionDays.ONE_WEEK,
  timeout: Duration.minutes(10),
  retryAttempts: 2,
  description: "Create the instruction PDF for users to download from Etsy",
  environment: {
    OUTPUT_BUCKET: importedBucketName,
  },
  layers: [this.chromiumLayer],
});
```

**Lambda JS Code:**

```
const puppeteer = require("/opt/nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer-core");
const chromium = require("/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@sparticuz/chromium");

async function createPdf(fileLinks, logoDataUri, bucketName, key) {
  let browser;
  try {
    // Launching browser
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: chromium.args,
      defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
      executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
      headless: chromium.headless,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

}
```

**Lambda Layer Package.json:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@sparticuz/chromium": "119.0.2",
    "puppeteer-core": "21.5.0"
  },
```